# Inserting unique rows without updating old ones

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-select

I have two similar tables in different databases, I want to insert into one from the other one. At the same time I want to ensure that every time mySql encounters a 'duplicate id' error it inserts the row at the bottom of the new table and assigns a new unique id. I have tried:
`INSERT...SELECT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
But I can't find a way to get it to insert into a new row if it finds 'duplicate keys' instead of updating the previous row.

Comment: Is the 'key' an autoincrement value? If so, I may have a solution for you. Try 'INSERT INTO `table2` SELECT NULL, col1, col2, col3 FROM table1' I don't have the exact syntax at hand, but it should work that way.

Comment: yes the 'key' is an autoincrement field. Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: You're welcome. It'd be nice to hear if you get it to work :)

Comment: @ATaylor I tried your code... it worked :D I think you should take a look at what eggyal came up with #cleanCode. Thanks!

Comment: That's good to hear. I also posted it as regular answer, but of course eggyval's answer is far superior. You may want to give him 'correct answer' status. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assign new `id` to every record being copied to the destination table, irrespective of whether the `id` in the source table existed previously in the destination or not, you can simply not provide the `id` and allow MySQL to resort to the default `NULL` value that causes an `auto_increment` value to be assigned:

```
INSERT INTO destdb.tbl (colA, colB, colC)
SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM   srcdb.tbl
```

Otherwise, you will need to use something like [`NULLIF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) to set `id` explicitly to `NULL` where it already exists, based on joining the tables together in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO destdb.tbl (id, colA, colB, colC)
SELECT NULLIF(src.id, dst.id), src.colA, src.colB, src.colC
FROM   srcdb.tbl src LEFT JOIN destdb.tbl dst USING (id)
```

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about NULLIF. I shall try to remember it, if I should ever need something like this. +1

Comment: @ATaylor: There are quite a few handy functions buried away in MySQL; it's well worth spending an hour scanning through the manual pages when bored on a train.  Has saved me so much pain!  :)

Comment: Yeah, I know exactly what you mean :) Unfortunately 'train rides' with internet access are so very rare for me :D

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-select.html, this may be achieved with the query:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` SELECT (NULL, col1, col2, col3) FROM `table1`
```

This way, the autoincrement-value is left with 'NULL', causing the engine to give it a new AI-value instead of trying to force the existing one in there.

Please don't stone me for the syntax, I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

```
If the id is autoincrement:
Create an additional column in the second table with a reference to the id value in the first table
Sample Select Query: 

SELECT unique_id, data FROM table_1 WHERE id='$id'

Sample Insert Query: 

INSERT INTO table_2 (table_1_unique_id, data) VALUES ($unique_id_from_first_table, $data)

This will solve any duplicate id problems and allow referencing between the two tables
```